# Error on NSFetchRequest inside "do"

Tags: cocoa, swift2, nsfetchrequest

In my Swift 2 OS X app I have this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Errors thrown from here are not handled" because indeed there's no `catch` following your `do`. You should add something like this:

```
do {
    ...
    for user in result {
        ...
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```